# Why don't developers run games on clusters?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, server, cluster-computing, game-engine

With multicores now more common, game developers are now leaning toward the use of threads, which is discussed in this question:

[Why don't large programs (such as games) use loads of different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571766/why-dont-large-programs-such-as-games-use-loads-of-different-threads)

To me, this idea seems analogous to the idea having multiple machines running things in clusters, or parallel computing.

Some games run on dedicated servers.

My question is: Can you use clusters to maximize parallel power, in the same way threading does on a multi-core system? Will it give the same benefit? Why/why not?

Comment: Why not ? Nothing is holding admins back to divide the load on the server side... .

Comment: I've heard it's uncommon though. And something about bottlenecks or such. I really don't know enough about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that. But sharing the computation of a Game engine between clusters will introduce more bottleneck to the system. Because clusters will us the network and it is way slower than CPU and main memory.

Some games use simulation clients to share large computing loads. But they need to be pretty careful about the synchronization issues caused by the network delays.